# PHP find multiple words in string and wrap in <span> tags

Tags: php

Im finding keyword "paintball" in a string, and wrapping it in span tags to change it colour to red like this...

```
$newoutput = str_replace("Paintball", "<span style=\"color:red;\">Paintball</span>", $output); 

echo $newoutput;
```

Which works, but people are writing it in the field as "Paintball", "paintball", "Paint Ball", "paint ball" etc.

Is there a better way of doing this rather than repeating it for every word?

Ideally something like...

```
$words = "Paintball", "paintball", "Paint Ball", "paint ball";

$newoutput = str_replace("($words)", "<span>$1</span>", $output);
```

But im not sure how to write it.

**Ok, so a mixture of answers got me here...**

```
$newoutput = preg_replace("/(paint\s*ball|airsoft|laser\s*tag)/i", "<span>$1</span>", $output); 
    echo $newoutput;
```

And it works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: If you are asking whether there is a PHP function like `wrapWordWithWordsMagicallyRelatedSomehow()` then no I don't think that is in PHP yet.

Comment: If that is not what you want could you explain more in specific what you are looking for?

Comment: If you found your own answer please don't put it in your question! Just write an answer yourself!

Comment: Sorry, it was your answer which is why i marked yours, but i used the \s* from toms answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the modifier `i` for case insensitivity)

```
<?php

    $output = "LaSer Tag";
    $newoutput = preg_replace("/(Airsoft|Paintball|laser tag)/i", "<span style=\"color:red;\">$1</span>", $output); 
    echo $newoutput;

?>
```

**EDIT:**

Besides that this is invalid syntax:

```
$words = "Paintball", "paintball", "Paint Ball", "paint ball";
```

and you probably meant this:

```
$words = ["Paintball", "paintball", "Paint Ball", "paint ball"];
       //^ See here array syntax                              ^
```

You can use something like this then

```
$newoutput = preg_replace("/(" . implode("|", $words) . ")/i", "<span style=\"color:red;\">$1</span>", $output);
```

Comment: Actually, its kind of perfect. This allows me to list the words im looking for, and the /i saves me having to worry about the case. Thanks!

Comment: @Collins You're welcome! (BTW: updated my answer where you can use an array of words instead of writing them in the regex itself)

Comment: No need for the capture group, you can remove it and use `$0` instead of `$1` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `preg_replace`, passing it an array of words and doing a case-insensitive match using the `i` modifier:

```
$patterns = array('/paint\s?ball/i', '/airsoft/i', '/laser tag/i');
$newoutput = preg_replace($patterns, '<span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $string);
```

The `\s?` in `/paint\s?ball/` matches zero or one spaces - you could use `\s*` to match zero or more instead if you preferred.

Comment: was literally about to post this.. oh well here is the example anyway lol ... https://ideone.com/dpyGJH

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to use

```
$title  =   get_the_title($post->ID);
$arraytitle = explode(" ", $title);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arraytitle);$i++){
    if($i == 0){
        echo $arraytitle[0].' ';
    }elseif($i >= 0){
        echo '<span>'.$arraytitle[$i].'</span>'." ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
function colorMyWord($word, $output)
{
   $target_words = array('paintball', 'paint ball', 'airsoft');
   if(in_array($target_words, $word))
   {
      $newoutput = str_ireplace($word, "<span style=\"color:red;\">$word</span>", $output); 

 return $newoutput;
}
```

Usage :

```
echo colorMyWord('Paintball', 'I need a Paintball');
```